# Postgres error using group query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

When executing `User.group(:type).count` I received the following error:

ERROR:  column "users.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used a default scope to order the User.  When I changed the query to `User.unscope(:order).group(:type).count` it worked properly.

This pushes me to agree with people who warn against using any default scopes.

Comment: I ran into this same issue when switching a project from mysql to postgres.  I ended up removing most of my default scopes as well.